# Unable to compile node-runtime

Tags: substrate

I am unable to compile node-runtime on the substrate v1.0 branch (as part of running ./scripts/build.sh from the substrate git repo base directory as per the installation instructions). The error I get is:

`error: cannot find macro proc_macro_call! in this scope
   --> /substrate/node/runtime/src/lib.rs:210:1
    |
210 | / construct_runtime!(
211 | |     pub enum Runtime with Log(InternalLog: DigestItem<Hash, AuthorityId, AuthoritySignature>) where
212 | |         Block = Block,
213 | |         NodeBlock = node_primitives::Block,
...   |
234 | |     }
235 | | );
    | |__^`

This had previously worked fine for me on the same machine but no matter what I try now, I cannot get this to compile anymore. My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL.

I suspected it could have been related to the latest Rust release 1.37.0 as that was the only change to my environment that I'm aware of since last building. But I have tried building with 1.35.0, 1.36.0, 1.37.0 and the 1.39.0-nightly all with same the issue. I have also tried completely blowing away my .cargo directory and starting from a fresh clone of the substrate v1.0 branch.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also clashed with this problem yesterday and began to looking for ways of solving. All, that you need to do is, downgrade nightly version. You can use this command:

*`$ rustup toolchain install nightly-2019-08-16`*

and then

*`$ rustup default nightly-2019-08-16`*

After this, when you'll begin to launch ./scripts/build.sh, you will clash with a new trouble that is connected with WASM. For the decision of this issue use this command:

*`$ rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly`*

As a result, you can use *build.sh* and also when you will launch *cargo build --release*, it will work!